# leaflet: how to remove "finish", "delete last point" and "cancel" submenu under polygon draw control?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

is anybody know how ti to remove "finish", "delete last point" and "cancel" submenu under polygon draw control?

tried different ways, like display:none for class leaflet-draw-actions, but nothing helps.

Comment: `.leaflet-draw-actions {
  display: none !important;
}` it will hide all your actions. Actions in edit, delete

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**

```
.leaflet-draw-actions {
  display: none !important;
}
```

**Or this one**

```
L.Draw.Toolbar.include({
    finish: false,
    cancel: false
});

new L.Control.Draw({
    edit: {
        edit: false,
        featureGroup: drawnItems
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: .leaflet-draw-actions {
  display: none !important;
}   this one worked for me